Why does the POSIX C shared memory IPC API requires permissions (read/write) in multiple places?
I'm trying to use the POSIX shared memory IPC API in C, which basically follows the pattern shm_open() -> ftruncate() -> mmap() -> use -> munmap() -> shm_unlink() (the latter two being optional IIUC). I noticed that the first two calls requires you different flags specifying permissions and options, but I can't figure out the difference. From the man pages:
int shm_open(const char *name, int oflag, mode_t mode);
                               ---------  -----------
                                 FIRST      SECOND

oflag is a bit mask created by ORing together exactly one of O_RDONLY or O_RDWR
       O_RDONLY
              Open the object for read access.  A shared memory object opened in this way can be mmap(2)ed only for read (PROT_READ) access.

       O_RDWR Open the object for read-write access.

       O_CREAT
              Create  the shared memory object if it does not exist.  The user and group ownership of the object are taken from the corresponding effec‐
              tive IDs of the calling process, and the object's permission bits are set according to the low-order 9 bits of  mode,  except  that  those
              bits set in the process file mode creation mask (see umask(2)) are cleared for the new object.  A set of macro constants which can be used
              to define mode is listed in open(2).  (Symbolic definitions of these constants can be obtained by including <sys/stat.h>.)

and then
void *mmap(void *addr, size_t length, int prot, int flags, int fd, off_t offset);
                                      --------
                                       THIRD

 The prot argument describes the desired memory protection of the mapping (and must not conflict with the open mode of the file).   It  is  either
       PROT_NONE or the bitwise OR of one or more of the following flags:

       PROT_EXEC  Pages may be executed.

       PROT_READ  Pages may be read.

       PROT_WRITE Pages may be written.

       PROT_NONE  Pages may not be accessed.

My question is: what's the difference between the permissions given in the three highlighted places?
A few things I noticed:

you can specify O_RDONLY in shm_open(), but then to allocate some space in the virtual file with ftruncate() you need to have permissions to write anyway (O_RDWR), so what's the point?
why is this required, and in the same call I have to set the bitmask for file permissions (SECOND in the example)
a second question: then you specify access protection for mmap too, but it also said that After the mmap() call has returned, the file descriptor, fd, can be closed immediately without invalidating the mapping., so I guess if you want to create a read only file (because other processes may write to it) you have to first open it with write privileges, then map it in read only mode, then deallocate the fd?


A file system entry has access rights, at least three "groups" of "authorisations" (read, write, execute) for owner, group owner and others.
These are used when a process request an access to that object; the requested accesses are tested against these autorisations.
When you "open" something you request an intent, this is specified in the oflag parameter (I want to read RD_ONLY, or I want to write, or...). Sometimes you request to open something that does not exists and at the same time to create it if necessary (O_CREAT). In that case, you need to specify what will be the access rights through the mode parameter.
Once you opened that object, you can use it as you declared in the opening. In the case of a shared memory object you need to map it into the process address space to be able to access it. This is the purpose of mmap, to map that object at some location in the memory of your process. Any chunk of memory of an address space is also protected; for example the code of your process is (by default) protected against writes, etc. Thus if you map a shared memory object you need to specify what will be the protection of that memory, that is the purpose of the prot parameter.

Thanks, the point I missed for the first difference was that mode flags are considered only when creating a new file with the O_CREAT oflag. Regarding the second: is this the same mechanism by which an executable I build is allowed as user=rwx on the filesystem, but the text section of the same file in memory is protected against writes? But then, why do we need to specify our intent for the shm_open oflag, since the shared memory can only be used via mmap (which is protected too)?

@AlessandroBertulli shm_open doesn't know what prot value you intend to pass to mmap. It can't just default to opening read-write, because the current permissions might not allow it.

@AlessandroBertulli You may get a file handle that some library opens for you (imagine in read/write opening mode), but your intent is just to read inside the mapping and ensure it ==> PROT_READ. You may also have different intents at different times for the same object.

I have no answer beyond the solid answer from Jean-Baptiste Yunès and comment from Ian Abbot, however there are some side-angles that may be interesting and worth examining.
As the permissions around what processes can open and map the shared memory are focused on owner, group and others permissions, it's notable that any process with the right permissions is free to join in (so long as it knows the right file path). As such, this is biased against the application(s) themselves having control over what processes can access the shared memory. This may or may not be non-optimal for an application. However, shared memory can sometimes be too open.
For example, an arbitrary code vulnerability in a web browser if exploited allows the attacker to access any shared memory exposed by any processes run by the same user (if they know the path).
If that kind of thing is of concern, then consolidating the processes as threads inside a single process helps; the memory can then be all in-process and not exposed outside of the process. Of course, a lot depends on the application(s), etc.
One possibility is, instead of using shm, to use ZeroMQ. This may be too radical a re-think of the application architecture you are pursuing, but it has some interesting properties that may be of interest.
It's an actor-model framework, so very unlike shared memory. However, it's inproc transport is effectively in-process memory sharing (well, copying) and so is likely fairly fast.
Second, if units of execution (threads, processes) are sharing data using ZeroMQ, all the other transports (ipc, tcp, vmci etc) can be brought to bear, and mixed / matched. So execution units can be readily recast as threads, separate processes, or as processes on separate machines, without any real source code changes. Its built in encryption / security library (libsodium, I think) means that, cast as separate processes, there can be privacy / security within the application without necessarily exposing everything to any process run by the user.
The speed of inproc is worth considering. It is copying data (quite how many times I'm not certain, but possibly only once), whereas use of shared memory (via shm) does not copy data. It's worth bearing in mind that accessing shared memory from multiple cores (or, worse, separate CPUs) has some overheads in the microelectronics of the CPU; there may be a lot of cache management chat between cores, and depending on exactly what the application does there could be a lot of cache misses. All in all on modern CPUs, if it suits the application, it can make sense to have a separate copy of the data for different threads / processes, mediated by an actor model framework like ZeroMQ.
